# varbinary pdf from database has been crash?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, pdf

This is how I retrieve `varbinary` pdf from my database and view in my asp.net page ,

```
byte[] pdfFile= null;
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 1 ).SingleOrDefault().pdfColumn;
pdfFile = new byte[obj.Length];

if (pdfFile!= null)
{
     Response.ClearHeaders();
     Response.Clear();
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfFile.Length.ToString());
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
     Response.BinaryWrite(pdfFile);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
}
```

When I view my pdf using this code , I got this message

[image: PDF Showing]

My `obj` returns likes

[image: Byte2]

The content of byte array ( `pdfFile` ) return likes

[image]

And my pdf file doesn't shown ! What wrong in my code ?

Comment: What is the type of `obj` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , This works for me :)

```
byte[] pdfFile= null;
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 1 ).SingleOrDefault().pdfColumn;

pdfFile = obj.ToArray();

 if (pdfFile!= null)
   {
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfFile.Length.ToString());
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
 Response.BinaryWrite(pdfFile);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are just creating a byte array with the correct length of obj but you are not actually putting the contents of obj into the pdfFile array.

What happens if you...

```
byte[] pdfFile= null;
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 1 ).SingleOrDefault().pdfColumn;
pdfFile = new byte[obj.Length];

obj.CopyTo(pdfFile);
```

Both the error you are seeing and blank page being displayed are quite often symptoms of the pdf file being all binary zeros or if you are using a stream then the streams position being at the end. You can easily determine if this is the case by running in debug and inspecting the contents of the byte array or stream just before you send it down the pipe. Check for the length and the content, it should look like binary, not just all zeros!

Comment: Yes , Rich Andrews . It's return like `{byte[88814]}` , not all zero :)

Comment: And the content of the byte array looks normal?

Comment: oh , my regret Rich Andrews . The content of the byte array returns all zero . I just edited my question :)

Comment: Cool, I just saw it - try the CopyTo method I mentioned earlier - if thats fails too then check you actually have content in the obj array too

Comment: yes, I have content in my obj array , but not in my pdfFile and I don't see `obj.CopyTo` method . Can you show me some other reference ?

Comment: CopyTo() is a method on an array, what type is obj that is being returned from your db context? Is it an array or a stream?